# Mapbox API /styles/v1/{username} doesn't reflect latest style data

Tags: api, mapbox

After calling Update Styles (POST) or Delete Styles (DELETE) using the Mapbox Styles API a subsequent call to List Styles (GET /styles/v1/{username}) returns stale style data. e.g. after calling DELETE and then calling CREATE the GET call will still return the deleted style!

Waiting about 5 minutes will usually return the latest, correct style data. Clearly some caching happening on the Mapbox end but deletes or updates should be reflected immediately.

Anybody confirm or provide a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed because of how our default caching behavior works for these API endpoints.

The style list endpoint specifically has a default Cache-Control value of 5 minutes (i.e. `Cache-Control: max-age=300`). You can confirm by looking at the headers of the API response:

[image: dev tools network tab with cache]

It's possible to get around this default behavior by including the query parameter `fresh=true` in your request. Making your full request look like:

```
GET /styles/v1/{username}?access_token={scopes:styles.list}&fresh=true
```

Including this query parameter will cause the API to serve you a response with `Cache-Control: no-cache` instead, and you will see the most up-to-date style information associated with the username:

[image: dev tools network tab with no-cache]

---

⚠️ disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: THANK YOU!! I've been developing and using a web app **for months** which allows users to select their datasets in a dropdown and then interactively modify their features on a map (kinda like the dataset editor in Mapbox Studio, but tailored to our business needs). **The app would always show stale data** which was a **real pain** for us because we have to navigate between datasets frequently and need up-to-date data! Now it's finally solved! Thank you!!

*PS: Maybe this should be added to the official docs so future developers will have no difficulty to find the solution to this problem.*