# Cache header for tilelayer png of mapbox

Tags: php, validation, png, mapbox, expires-header

I use mapbox but i have one problem for validate this in Gmetrix

There are 4 static components without a far-future expiration date.

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/12/2103/1460?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/12/2104/1460?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/12/2103/1461?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/12/2104/1461?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw

This picture are served with an expiration at 12h and i want to put this with a a far-future expiration date. a far-future expiration date

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624873/mapbox-api-styles-v1-username-doesnt-reflect-latest-style-data

Answer (score 1):

In answer to this question the problem came from using the leaflet script for mapbox which generated these images at the corresponding line:

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw'

If you use mapbox directly with your toke and without leaflet there's no problem